# Excel formula to look for a sequence of values and return row number

Tags: excel-formula

I have one column I am trying to look through where I am looking for an instance of a value on a row and then checking if the value in the cell directly below that matches another criteria.

The output is a report where I am looking for a match on a machine name and a match on a shift name and then give me a row number on where that is in the list. I am the using this as a starting point for allsorts of lookups I will do thereon. I just need the start point of each machine across three shifts in the dataset.

I've added some images of the source data and output table I am trying to build. Essentially I am looking the machine name up from the left of the output matrix and the shift from the header of the matrix and trying to acquire the row number from the source a data which is all in column B.

The look up range is `$B$2:$B$5000`

Criteria for the first match to be cell `$I2` content, Criteria for the row below would be matching cell `$K1` content for the 1st cell of the matrix that is.

As you can see I was successful with the first column but failed thereon. This is the formula I used t get the matches for the machine across the first shift that appeared but as the formula is it's not really testing for two criteria's. it finds a pass and fail in the logical and then gives up.

=IF(INDEX('Kiwi Rep A'!$B:$B,MATCH($I2,'Kiwi Rep A'!$B:$B,0)+1,0)=K$1,MATCH($I2,'Kiwi Rep A'!$B:$B,0),"Not Found")

[Source data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Inh.jpg)

[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWhCw.jpg)

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you have been using so far?

Comment: This finds the value of the first value I am looking for     =INDEX('Kiwi Rep A'!$B$1:$B$5000,SMALL(IF('Kiwi Rep A'!$B$1:$B$5000=I$3,ROW('Kiwi Rep A'!$B$1:$B$5000),"Not Found"),COLUMNS($K$1:K$1)),1)

Comment: This finds the second value      =INDEX('Kiwi Rep A'!$B$1:$B$5000,SMALL(IF('Kiwi Rep A'!$B$1:$B$5000=I$3,ROW('Kiwi Rep A'!$B$1:$B$5000),"Not Found"),COLUMNS($K$1:K$1)),1)

Comment: The output is a report where I am looking for a match on a machine name and a match on a shift name and then give me a row number on where that is in the list. I am the using this as a starting point for allsorts of lookups I will do thereon. I just need the start point of each machine across three shifts in the dataset

Comment: =IF(INDEX('Kiwi Rep A'!$B:$B,MATCH($I2,'Kiwi Rep A'!$B:$B,0)+1,0)=K$1,MATCH($I2,'Kiwi Rep A'!$B:$B,0),"Not Found")    worked really well for finding the first instance of the machines for the first shift but then struggled moving onto achieving the second and 3rd shifts

Comment: If you are able to add an example (picture or text) of the data that the code looks through. A line or two of data should be enough. Gives me a bit more of an understanding as to what your code is looking through and looking for.

Comment: No idea how to get the image in here. I read the help notes, still no idea ;))

Comment: You wont be able to add it to the comments section, but if you edit your original post, and just add it to the end it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the data from? It seems that you try to do some machine statistics from log files. How often do you need to run this?

You should consider to bring you data into a proper form first. RegEx might help here. For one-time actions this can probably be done best using an editor (like notpad++). For repeatable task there can be regex's be used in excel as well.

Anyhow with proper form I mean that you turn your report into a table by changing the CR/NL into tabs and load it into Excel as a table.But his might only be easy enough if the report has the same layout for each entry.

With the data as a table you can the use the Excel [DB-functions](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Dcounta-Function.html)

But depending on the data this might not be sufficient as well.